# Why does my anaconda virtual env say python=3.9 when I installed python=3.7

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I created a conda virtual environment with python version 3.7 and when I open my anaconda navigator --> Environments --> and click the virtual environment I created I see python 3.7 but when I go to the terminal --> activate my conda env --> and check the python version with `python --version` it outputs python 3.9.

Could someone explain to me what is going on?

**I've listed below some helpful information:**

- I'm using **Mac OS terminal** using Rosetta, intel processor x86-64.
- Shell: **Z-shell** (**zsh**)

Here is what I did in the terminal:

```
~$conda create -n tf python=3.7
~$conda activate tf
(tf)~$python --version
Python 3.9.9
```

Here is my **.zshrc**:

```
PROMPT='%n~$'

#export CFLAGS="-I//opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include"

#export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH

#alias python_brew=/usr/local/bin/python3

 
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi


# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Here is my **.zprofile**:

```
# sets gcc 11 as default gcc compiler (prevents from Xcode version being used)
# alias gcc='gcc-11'
# alias cc='gcc-11'
# alias g++='g++-11'
# alias c++='c++-11'
alias nanoz='nano ~/.zshrc'
alias zprofile='open ~/.zprofile'
 
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"


# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<


# PYENV
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
# End: delete for miniconda3 TensorFlow env to work


# Deactivates conda before running brew. 
# Re-activates conda if it was active upon completion.
brew() {
    local conda_env="$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV"
    while [ "$CONDA_SHLVL" -gt 0  ]; do
        conda deactivate
    done
    command brew $@
    local brew_status=$?
    [ -n "${conda_env:+x}" ] && conda activate "$conda_env"
    return "$brew_status"
}

#PATH TO MYSQL
#export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Not enough info - please edit. What "`python`" resolves to in a shell session depends on `PATH` and how that is manipulated in shell. At minimum `echo $PATH` before and after activation, but typically the problem is terminal-specific (what terminal and shell are used?) and we need to see shell init file (e.g., `.bashrc`).

Comment: I've edited my post to include the information you are looking for. I'm new to programming and still trying to get an understanding for shell files and how they work, so I just listed both my .zprofile and .zshrc.

Comment: Thanks. Please also add the `echo $PATH` before and after activation of the `tf` environment.